# Java generic instances in a list - generic observable and all

Tags: java, generics

How to properly model a list in Java which contains several instances of a generic type, with each instance not necessarily having the exact same concrete type parameters (but a shared common root type).

Consider the following M(N)WE (minimal (non-)working example):

```java
public interface Event {
}

public interface Listener<T extends Event> {
    void handle(T event);
}

public class Publisher {
    private List<Listener<? extends Event>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T extends Event> void addListener(final Listener<T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public <T extends Event> void publish(final T event) {
        for (final Listener<? extends Event> listener : listeners) {
            try {
                listener.handle(event); // *** this is not working: incompatible types
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How is one expected to specify the generic types (if at all)? Using raw types makes the code compile, but is ugly (and defeats using generics in the first place).

When trying to compile the above code, `javac` simply errors out with:

> incompatible types: T cannot be converted to CAP#1
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends Event declared in method publish(T)
>   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>   CAP#1 extends Event from capture of ? extends Event

Comment: The wildcard `?` means some unknown, but specific type. But `handle(event)` cannot be used, because the compiler doesn't know *what* type it is. To fix this – don't use generics at all; replace all `T`s with just `Event`.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterize the `Publisher` class. If you want it to be typesafe the `listeners` list needs to know about `T`.

```
public class Publisher<T extends Event> {
    private List<Listener<T>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(final Listener<T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void publish(final T event) {
        for (final Listener<T> listener : listeners) {
            try {
                listener.handle(event);
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be extra flexible you could loosen the listener bounds to accept any `T` or superclass of `T`.

```
public class Publisher<T extends Event> {
    private List<Listener<? super T>> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addListener(final Listener<? super T> listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void publish(final T event) {
        for (final Listener<? super T> listener : listeners) {
            try {
                listener.handle(event);
            } catch (final Exception ex) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this won't work for the usecase of the question. The publisher itself is not bound to any specific `T`. It should be able to handle any kind of `Event`. It will hold multiple different listeners (so maybe a `Listener<StartEvent>` and another listener `Listener<EndEvent>`)

Comment: Aren't you going to pass an `EndEvent` to a `Listener<StartEvent>`, then? Your publisher is going to pass the wrong kinds of events to the listeners. I believe the compiler is quite correctly identifying a type safety issue with your class design.

Comment: Hm yes, that's a very valid point. I guess I have to re-evaluate my expecations then …